# HM-10 doesn't responde after RENEW

Tags: bluetooth, ble

Today I finally got two HM-10 modules. I did flash firmware using [this](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=393655.0) tutorial. It worked until I didn't send `AT+RENEW` command. Now, LED blinks, I see device in BT terminal(Android phone) but I can't connect to it. Terminal says `Connection failed: write descriptor failed`. I tried sending commands over COM port from PC, but it doesn't responde.
Also I connected pin 11 to GND, problem is still here. Strange thing - After firmware flash, `AT+HELP` doesn't exist, while `AT+HELP?` returns some website.

For second module, LED doesn't blink but I see module in BT terminal. It also stopped working after `AT+RENEW`. When I try to connect, I get same error.

Comment: it is unclear what you are doing ... the tutorial that you linked is NOT for flashing firmware to an HM-10 ... it is possible that you broke the device by flashing the firmware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your COM serial baud rate to 115200. I had the same problem and the moment I change the baud rate on my Serial Com or Serial monitor. it works for me